# permisson in document and media library portlet

Tags: liferay

I'm using liferay 6.1 and I have some problems.
I defined a role named "student" and I want to add a basic document in Document and Media Library portlet as "student".I can do this as "admin" role but when I sign in as "student" I cant see the button "add". how can I give permission to this role?

Comment: you can simply add "Add Document" permission for Student role.

Comment: where can I add this permission?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Control Panel > Roles, then click on Action buttons and then Define permissions. Then select  Document and Media under Site Content and check "Add Document" permission and save.

Thus, Student role will have permission to add documents.